# creating a time series from a data set usig SAS

Tags: sas

I have a big data set like in the [image: pic]

and I want to create a time series for every **cont_no**. It means I want to have something like

[image]

I tried with

```
Proc timeseries data=contracts
out=timeseries;
by cont_no;
id date interval=MS_ID accumulate=total;
var exp_amount;
run
```

It is running for more hours without results.
How can I correct the code? Or probably I am not using the correct commands and "tool"  of SAS!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating a time series - you already *have* a time series.  You want to transpose the time series (though I wonder if you really do want to do that, but anyway).

If you first create a variable `year_month` with the year/month catted together, and start it with a A-Z character or underscore please, and then sort by cont_no, then this will work:

```
proc transpose data=contracts out=timeseries;
  by cont_no;
  var exp_amount;
  id year_month;
run;
```

But I'd encourage you to do time series analysis on the data as it is currently structured - this is a more useful structure in most cases for time series analysis than the horizontal structure.

Comment: Thanks Joe, you are write, but the problem is the data is really mixed without any order the advantage of it is to have the main data where I can look it.